# Run in R system ('g++ ...') got error 217

Tags: c++, r, windows, g++

I am trying to compile a `.cpp` file created by someone else in R on a Windows computer by running the following code:

```
system("g++ C:\\Users\\uos\\Documents\\R\\win-library\\3.2\\TimeShift\\data\\dtw.cpp -o C:\\Users\\uos\\Documents\\R\\win-library\\3.2\\TimeShift\\data\\dtw")
```

and I get

> error code 217

I have tried the following solutions:

1. use `system2` instead of `system`
2. use

   ```
   setwd(C:\\Users\\uos\\Documents\\R\\win-library\\3.2\\TimeShift\\data)
   system2('g++ dtw.cpp -o dtw')
   ```

and they both give me

> error 217

I have checked the path to the dtw and it is correct as well as installing the `Rcpp` package. I had a look on the `dtw.cpp` file and it seems OK. I do not know what else I could do.

Comment: If this is Rcpp code, why do you use `system`/`system2`?

Comment: I am using a package developed probably for linux, and this is the code they have. I am trying to change it as little as possible.

Comment: That's up to you. I would follow the standard way instead, i.e., make the package Rcpp-aware, include the cpp code in the package and compile during the build process.

Comment: Well, the command is inside a function that previously applies some R functions on the input data, then processes it using the  dtw.cpp function, and then further processes the output of dtw.cpp using some R functions so it is quite complicated this is why I want to keep the changes to a  minimum.

Comment: No, that's actually easy with Rcpp.